# DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet not recognizing sheet name

Tags: ms-access, vba

Here is the code:

```
strOut="C:\Users\....file.xlsx"
xlSheetName="WA100!"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acLink, TableName:="excelLink", FileName:=strOut, HasFieldNames:=True, Range:=xlSheetName
```

Is there a reason why this wouldn't work? It appears to be syntactically correct to me.

Comment: Is the exclamation mark actually part of the sheet name? If so, enclose it in single quotes, e.g. `xlSheetName = "'WA100!'"`. That said the `Range` argument is probably expecting a *range address*, not just a sheet name, so you want to pass it e.g. `'WA100!'!$A$1` (assuming the exclamation mark is part of the sheet name).

Comment: @Eleyna Do you get run-time error 3125 when you attempt to run that code?

Comment: @HansUp yes, I am!

Comment: @Eleyna  So how committed are you to keeping an exclamation point in the sheet name?  If you can live without it, change the name to just WA100, save the workbook, close Excel, and run your VBA code with this change: `xlSheetName="WA100$"`  Works for me.

Comment: @HansUp Sorry, I didn't have an exclamation point in the name. It was just WA100. That was just part of how I indicated it was a sheet (should have worked like your $ did). This is bizarre, but when I copied and pasted that sheet into the same excel workbook with a different name, it works. Even when I switch it to the original name it works. But the original sheet won't work for anything. Guess at this point I have to toss it up to being a fluke and hope it doesn't happen again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List all the sheet names and see if they are what you think they are.

```
Sub SheetNames()
Columns(1).Insert
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(i).Name
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: My god, it was a space. I even checked for that early on. Don't know how I missed it. But that was the issue, thanks -.-

Comment: Yeah, I had to learn the hard way too.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?  Modify to suit your needs.  Also, can you get rid of the '!' symbol, at least for testing purposes.  Make it work in a simple context, and then you can work your way up to more and more complex things.  Usually it's not a good idea to start with more complex things, unless you are really confident that you know what you are doing.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, 3, _ 
 "Employees","C:\Lotus\Newemps.wk3", True, "A1:G12"
```

This is a good resource for topics pertaining to DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet.

http://access-excel.tips/access-vba-cocmd-transferspreadsheet/

Comment: Ok so using your method, I've deduced that it is definitely the sheet name that is causing the error. If I change it to A1:B3 it works. What's tripping me up is that in my code, this is a function and I pass the sheet name as an argument. I use this function in another sub and it works perfectly fine to pass the sheet name "WA250" but not the sheet name "WA6100" (even though both exist in the excel file).....

Comment: Can you set 'Option Explicit' right at the top of the script and Dim the Worksheet name as String?  After you do that, the error should be obvious, I think...

Comment: just did that and still getting a run-time error 3125. It says that it "is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long"

Comment: Perhaps there is a space at the beginning or end of the Worksheet name, and that's why it's throwing an error.